# Whats the best way to log method calls?

Tags: c#, logging, aop

i need to log each method call in my application.
i dont want to repeat code in each method of the business layer

i have been looking at the AOP approach which seems to be the best option right now but i have no idea how to use this method.

any suggestions or links articles or examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PostSharp](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/337564/Aspect-Oriented-Programming-Using-Csharp-and-PostS) which is an APO infrastructure and you have a nice example on that link for ways of using it.

If you need any logging infrastructure too you can use [log4net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14819/How-to-use-log4net).

From the links above, you can see the log attribute example that you can just modify for using a logging infrastructure as well:

```
[Serializable]
public class LogAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);

        Console.WriteLine("Entering [ {0} ] ...", args.Method);

        base.OnEntry(args);
    }

    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Leaving [ {0} ] ...", args.Method);

        base.OnExit(args);
    }
}
```

using it on your code:

```
[LogAspect]
public void SomeMethod()
{
}
```

which will log on `SomeMethod` call

Comment: Thanks eyossi . i will try it out now