# Event AnyMethodCalled vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need to run this code after every method is executed:

```
Debug.WriteLine(System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())
```

A nice solution would be an event 'AnyMethodCalled' which would be fired after any method is fired. Is there anything like this? Or do I have to add this line to every Sub in my class?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011214/whats-the-best-way-to-log-method-calls) seems relevant.

Comment: Do you know about the call stack?